# Accessing state in a parent component from a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I'm currently accessing the state of a parent component in a child component through the use of callbacks, but I'm not quite sure how it works:

```
export default function parentComponent({ type }) {

    const
         [inEditMode, setInEditMode] = useState(false)

return (
        <>
        
            <div className={containerCssClasses}>
                    <childComponent onCancel={() => { setInEditMode(false); }} type={type} />
```

here, the parent component is calling the child component and passing an anonymous function to the component for it to call back.

In the child component:

```
function childComponent({onCancel}) {
 return (
    <div>
        <Button onClick={() => onCancel()} variant="link" >
    </div?
 );
}
```

I am a bit confused how this is able to work properly if the child component doesn't have access to setInEditMode(). I understand that when passing a function to another function (in this case, a component), it is passed by reference. But does that necessarily mean all of the variables within that function are passed by reference as well? I am new to react (and javascript), but when I looked this concept up I couldn't find a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is the right way to go. More than callbacks these functions you pass down to child components are call props and I invite you to read the documentation about them.

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

You can also find very detailed articles about it:

https://itnext.io/what-is-props-and-how-to-use-it-in-react-da307f500da0

Whatever you'll pass from the parent to the child can be used in the child component as if it was called in the parent one.

In your case the child is indeed gonna trigger setInEditMode(false)

As you're not passing any variable to it you can actually call it as such:

```
<Button onClick={onCancel} variant="link" >
```

Comment: Oh I see. I'm used to static languages so I am having a hard time wrapping my head around the fact that the parent component can alter the state of a child component just by passing a reference to a function. Is this just something that happens behind the scenes due to React? Outside of React, is this something that can be accomplished with vanilla javascript?

Comment: One last question: I thought props were read only? Isnt the child calling a function that changes the state of the property inEditMode though?

Comment: Well react is itself coded in Javascript so it's just a syntax that was created. But it's kinda passing a function or callback to another function at the end.

Comment: The props are indeed read only. Here you read the function that it self is triggering an action on the state (editMode is a state not a props). But activate a function is reading it. You are not reassigning the function to another value.

Answer (score 0):

The parent component's state you pass to child component as props is not updated as parent's state is changed. so, you need a callback function to access parent's current state at any given time. Also, if you have dependent state value in parent and child component or rather multiple components, you can move it to reducer if you're using redux for state management.